# Python3 production: logging exceptions without using traceback module

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, production

In our production code, we log errors like this:

```
error = {'tos': str(sys.exc_info()[0:2])}
```

But it only allows to see this kind of info about the error:

```
"tos": "(<class 'AttributeError'>, AttributeError(\"'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'\",))"
```

Which is not enough - I want to see line number and name of the file with code. However, I could get that info with this code:

```
import traceback
meta['error'] = {'tos': str(traceback.format_exc())}
```

But we DO NOT use `traceback` module in production because it is considered too heavy. So how can I get line number and filename without using `traceback`?

Answer (score 1):

[`sys.exc_info`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info) returns the tuple of 3 elements, where the third is the traceback.

The returned tuple is like - `(type, value, traceback)` .

You are doing - `str(sys.exc_info()[0:2])` which only selects first two elements.

Try -

```
str(sys.exc_info())
```

If you cannot use the traceback module to format the traceback. And if you just want the exception's line number and filename, you can use the following -

```
sys.exc_info()[2].tb_frame.f_code.co_filename #<---- filename
sys.exc_info()[2].tb_lineno # <------ line number
```

Please note these can be internal names, and best is to use `traceback` module.

Comment: I already tried it, it only adds <traceback object at 0x1dd68c988>

Comment: Please check latest answer.

Comment: Yeah, I really get the line number and filename, bit it doesn't tell me much - I really do need to trace it up to the last function call before the exception. Is there a way to do it or the only way is thru traceback module?

Comment: I believe only through traceback module. Otherwise it may get very very very complicated.